# unity animation error resulting in animations not changing by the parameters

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I am working in Unity and trying to create an animation controller that changes the direction the player is facing by playing a different animation while a button is pressed.

I keep getting this error "*Assets/Maps/Map1/Entities/Player/PlayerMovement.cs(6,18): warning CS0649: Field `PlayerMovement.animator' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value`null'*"

This error does not stop the game from playing, but the animation stays in its default position.

This is the code I have as a player controller which is where I alter the parameters for the animation controller. It tells me the error is on line 6 space 18.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
Animator animator;
public float movementSpeed = 100.0f;
public bool Movement = true;
public int Direction = 0;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    animator.GetComponent<Animator> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (Movement == true) {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
            transform.Translate ((Vector2.up) * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            animator.SetInteger("Direction",0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {
            transform.Translate ((-Vector2.right) * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            animator.SetInteger("Direction",270);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) {
            transform.Translate ((-Vector2.up) * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            animator.SetInteger("Direction",180);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
            transform.Translate ((Vector2.right) * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            animator.SetInteger("Direction",90);
        }
        else{
            animator.SetInteger("Direction",360);
        }
    }

}
}
```

this is an Imgur link to Screen shots of the animator gui for unity. I would have put them directly on this screen, but I don't have the permissions to do that.

[Imgur Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwB9F.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I beleive this is the culprit:

```
   void Start () {
    animator.GetComponent<Animator> ();
     }
```

it is not being assinged it should be like this :

```
               void Start ()
               {
             //you have to use the variable u declared and assing it to the animator
              animator = this.GetComponent<Animator> ();
              }
```

hope that solves it.

Comment: That got rid of the error, but the animation still wont change. It now gives me multiple runtime errors saying _Animator has not been initialized.
UnityEngine.Animator:SetInteger(String, Int32)_ which is odd because this is the exact way that I used in my playermovement script

Comment: ok lets see this step by step 

1:the object to which the script is attached , does it have an animator component in the editor ? if yes then does it have the animator controller(the one you showed in the picture) dragged into it ? if yes then lets see .
2:ok then remove all your code in the update and do this:                      if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) { animator.setInteger("Direction",0);}        now make sure you have the game window and animator state window opened at the same time and check to see if this one animation works .

Comment: everything I have is set up correctly. Did what you said and there is still no animation.

Comment: scratch that... I can walk right and have the animation play. any other direction does not work.

Comment: ok so there is improvement hmmmmm for animation to play in other directions you need to do changes in rotation have you made your animation accordingly ??

Comment: I'm positive in the fact that I have. everything is working when I walk to the right and it is set up exactly the same for the other directions.

Comment: did you ever got it to work ? you can send it to me so i can take a look at it